# How do I export a photo from apple photos using JXA?

Tags: export, javascript-automation, apple-photos

I'm trying to use javascript-for-automation on my Mac to export images from Apple Photos but I can't get around a `Can't convert types` error.

The problematic line in my code is `Photos.export( { export: matchingPhotos, to: destination } )` but I don't know how to fix it. I really only want to export `randomPhoto`, not the whole list of `matching_photos`, but I'm trying to get this to work first, because `matching_photos` is definitely a list of media items. I think the problem is the type of the destination, which should be a 'file'.

This is what I have from the Photos Dictionary in Apple's Script Editor

> **export** *method* : Export media items to the specified location as files
> 　**export** list of [MediaItem](#) : The list of media items to export.
> 　　**to:** file : The destination of the export.
> 　　**[usingOriginals: boolean]** : Export the original files if true, otherwise export rendered jpgs. defaults to false.

My code, which I'm running from the command line with `echo "$(osascript -l JavaScript <<'EOT'`...:

```js
const posix_path="/Users/erik/dev/temp/"
const destination=Path(posix_path)
const Photos=Application("Photos")
Photos.includeStandardAdditions = true //  What does this accomplish?
matchingPhotos=Photos
    .search({for:"ravens"})
    .filter(x=>x.filename().match(/(jpeg|jpg|heic)$/i)
)
if (matchingPhotos.length>0){
    const randomPhoto = matchingPhotos[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * matchingPhotos.length)
    ]
    console.log("foo")
    Photos.export({ export: matchingPhotos, to: destination } )
    console.log("bar")
    randomPhoto.size()
} else {
    0
}
```

The output:

```
foo
execution error: Error: Error: Can't convert types. (-1700)
```

I've also tried `Photos.export( { export: matchingPhotos, to: posix_path } )` to see if that would work but it doesn't.

I can't find any relevant documentation or examples about using JXA to export from photos. Pointers to such material would be very helpful.

I managed to export a photo using AppleScript but I couldn't manage the list-filtering and got frustrated with the syntax.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The line causing the problem

```
Photos.export( { export: matchingPhotos, to: destination } )
```

should read

```
Photos.export( matchingPhotos, { to: destination } )
```

and to get only one photo it would be

```
Photos.export( [randomPhoto], {to: destination} )
```

Comment: I found the answer in the code of this github repository: [joeattardi/apple-photos-batch-export](https://github.com/joeattardi/apple-photos-batch-export/blob/main/src/library.js). Thanks 
Joe Attardi!